# No value given for one or more required parameters in connection initialisation

Tags: c#, connection

I have an C# form application that use an access database.

This application works perfectly in debug and release. It works on all version of Windows.
But it crash on one computer with Windows 7.

The message I got is:

`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.`

EDIT, after some debugging with messagebox on the computer that have the problem, here is the code that bug.The error is catched on the cmd.ExecuteReader(). The messagebox juste before is shown and the next one is the one in the catch with the exception below. Any ideas?

```
public List<CoeffItem> GetModeleCoeff()
    {

        List<CoeffItem> list = new List<CoeffItem>();
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader dr;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT nIDModelAquacad, nIDModeleBorne, fCoefficient FROM tbl_ModelBorne ORDER BY nIDModelAquacad", m_conn);
            MessageBox.Show("Commande SQL créée avec succès");

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Exécution du reader sans problème!");

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new CoeffItem(Convert.ToInt32(dr["nIDModelAquacad"].ToString()),
                    Convert.ToInt32(dr["nIDModeleBorne"].ToString()),
                    Convert.ToDouble(dr["fCoefficient"].ToString())));
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Lecture du reader");

            dr.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Fermeture du reader");
        }
        catch (OleDbException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur dans la lecture des modèles/coefficient: " + err.ToString());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I think it's something related to the connection string but why only on that computer.

Thanks for your help!

***EDIT***

Here is the complete error message:

See the end of this message for details on invoking

just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()

   at DatabaseLayer.DatabaseFacade.GetModeleCoeff()

   at DatabaseLayer.DatabaseFacade.InitConnection(String strFile)

   at CalculatriceCHW.ListeMesure.OuvrirFichier(String strFichier)

   at CalculatriceCHW.ListeMesure.nouveauFichierMenu_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Any chance this is Windows 7 x64 bit?

Comment: How is the value for strFile getting passed into InitConnection (or in the case of the one computer - NOT getting passed into the function)?

Comment: Darin: No it's x86

ktharsis: I don't know the value since it's not in debug, it's an installed version. If the things above and below doesn't work, I will put a message box or a log file so I can see the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please remove your evil `catch` block and then re-post the stack trace.

Comment: I just edit the stack trace without the catch block. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what happened.

The database missed 2 column in one table. The reason? Well, in the application, when the user click on "New", a copy is made of the .mdb in the application folder to the location of the choice of the user. The "model" database is ok, all the column are there, but the copied file was missing 2 column. So I did a little research, a found that the application was using the Virtual Store of Windows 7 instead of the program file directory. Why? We think that the user saved the file right in the program file directory (something that cause a copy in the virtual store) with the old version of the app (and of the database). At this moment, the virtual store was used in priority to the program file and everything was not working.

So thanks for all your help, it help me find the problem!

Answer (score 3):

You aren't escaping the file path.

You should use an [`OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), which will correctly escape paths with special characters, and will probably solve your problem.

For example:

```
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
builder.DataSource = strFile;
builder["User Id"] = "admin";
```

Answer (score 0):

It might pay to add this check to the start of your method, just to make it easier to tell when this method is not being called properly. Not sure whether this is the issue you are having, but it might rule out one possible bug.

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFile))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("strFile", "strFile must be set");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are lacking Initial Catalog, that is, DataBase you want to connect to.

Initial Catalog=YourDBName

Comment: I checked on connectionstrings.com and there is no need for Initial Catalog on an access database since there is only one database in the file. Thanks anyway :)